# Convert DOM elements to HTML Code and display in an on-page textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the need to grab a few DOM Elements from an HTML page and emit their HTML (code) into a textarea on the same page.  The purpose is to allow the viewer to copy and paste the code into their own pages.

Is this even possible?

I've tried something like (in jQuery):

```
$('textarea').val( $('.container').html() );
```

Where I've first cloned the elements I require into a `div.container`, but that just gives me something like `object #<HTMLImageElement>` in my textarea.  What I was hoping to get was something like `<img src="http://www.domain.com/images/file.png" alt="My Image">` according to the structure of the elements I cloned.

Any pointers appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/mf9xt/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

$('textarea').val( $('.container').get(0).innerHTML );

Comment: No need to clone this either.